# how to use json array for password validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, passwords

I'm trying to loop json array for password validation. Can someone help me.

```
var pwdarray= { "pwd":[ {  
     "TEXT":"Password must be at least 6 character(s) long.",
     "EXPRESSION":"\/(^(.){6,}$)\/"
  },
  {  
     "TEXT":"Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter(s).",
     "EXPRESSION":"/[a-z]/"
  }
  ]}
  var pswd ="textpasswordvalue";
  if (pswd.length < pwd.EXPRESSION) {
      $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    } else {
      $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    }
```

Comment: What do you need help with?  "Can someone help me" doesn't tell us much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put the `/` around the expression. Then you can convert it to a regular expression with `new RegExp`, and test the password with it. You can loop with `.every()`, which will perform tests as long as they're successful.

```js
var pwdarray = {
  "pwd": [{
      "TEXT": "Password must be at least 6 character(s) long.",
      "EXPRESSION": "^(.){6,}$"
    },
    {
      "TEXT": "Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter(s).",
      "EXPRESSION": "[a-z]"
    }
  ]
}
$("#check").click(function() {
  var pswd = $("#pass").val();
  $("#error").text("Password is good").addClass('valid').removeClass('invalid');
  pwdarray.pwd.every(({
    TEXT: text,
    EXPRESSION: exp
  }) => {
    if (!new RegExp(exp).test(pswd)) {
      $("#error").text(text).addClass('invalid').removeClass('valid');
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  color: red;
}

.valid {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="pass">
<button id="check">Check</button>
<div id="error"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code to test each expression with the password

```
var valid = true;
var message;

for(var k in pwdarray.pwd){
    var regex = new RegExp(pwdarray.pwd[k].EXPRESSION);
    if(pswd.search(regex) > -1){
        valid = false;
        message = pwdarray.pwd[k].TEXT;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to access your `EXPRESSION` like `pwdarray['pwd'][index]['EXPRESSION']` where `index` is a integer. That could come from a for-loop. Second you need to [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) your `pswd` with your regular-expression.

```js
var pwdarray = { 
  "pwd": [ 
    {  
     "TEXT":"Password must be at least 6 character(s) long.",
     "EXPRESSION":"\/(^(.){6,}$)\/"
    },
    {  
     "TEXT":"Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter(s).",
     "EXPRESSION":"/[a-z]/"
    }
  ]
};

var pswd = "test";

for (var index in pwdarray['pwd'])
  if (pswd.match (pwdarray['pwd'][index]['EXPRESSION']))
    $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
  else {
    $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
    document.write (pwdarray['pwd'][index]['TEXT']);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```